# How to use an Excel User-defined function UDF in Sharepoint's list calculated column?

Tags: worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, sharepoint-2013

Thanks to a very good article found on the web, I have build a "TRANSLATE" fomula in Excel (actually VBA code that queries google translate and returns the translated word/sentence in the choosen language). i.e. =Translate(A1,"en","es") where A1 is CAR returns COCHE. It works perfectly in Excel, and I want to use it now in Sharepoint 2013 list to translate automatically (calculated column) the text of some other columns.

Anybody could help on that topic?

Thanks in advance.

NEO

Answer (score 0):

An Excel VBA UDF runs only in Excel. You can't use it in a calculated SharePoint column.

Don't shoot the messenger.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same issue with a UDf for a timestamp. I'm not an admin for SharePoint but our IT team is currently working on the solution. Here is a link from Microsoft'd site on how to make a UDF work in Sharepoint.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-deploy-udfs-using-sharepoint-foundation-solutions

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.